# Get Children in jqGrid Treeview Adjacency Model

Tags: jqgrid, treeview

I have used jqGrid Treeview Adjacency model to display the hierarchy. Treeview works perfectly with no problem . But i want to retrieve the children for node . I already have the id of that row . I have written code like this

```
var record = jQuery("#Listtbl").jqGrid('getInd',rowid);
newRecord =  $('#Listtbl').jqGrid('getNodeChildren',record);
```

but in new record i always get all records instead of children .

Comment: did you verify the `recode` has the right value...?

Comment: record returns the right index of that row , but getNodeChildren never returns the children of that row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use wrong value of `record` parameter of [getNodeChildren](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atreegrid#methods). You should use `getRowData` or `getLocalRow`:

```js
var localRow = $('#Listtbl').jqGrid('getLocalRow', "5"),
    children = $('#Listtbl').jqGrid('getNodeChildren', localRow);

alert(children.length);
```